# Javascript create array of objects dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a JSON response i.e.

```
[{"name":"title","value":"STEP-01","translation":"STEP-01"},{"name":"meta_description","value":"","translation":"meta desc"}, ......]
```

from this I want to create an array of objects dynamically so that I get `name` as key and `translation` as value
like

```
data.en = {
  title : 'STEP-01',
  meta-description :     meta desc
}
```

I have tried this but it creates an array

```
jsonObj = []

$.each(result, function (index, value) {

             lang_array =   {};
            lang_array[value.name]  =   value.translation;
            jsonObj.push(lang_array);

        })
```

Comment: That's becase `[]` is array synax. You need to use `{}`. You are overwriting `lang_array` value and it wipes out the `{}`

Comment: key-value can be achieved with an Object, not an array

Comment: He wants an array of objects, the code is doing exactly what he wants, at least what he described. `I want to create an array of objects dynamically`

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović, there are no key-value arrays or hashed arrays in JavaScript

Comment: @Roysh He has an ARRAY of OBJECTS, he wants an ARRAY of OBJECTS. `jsonObj = []; lang_array =   {}; jsonObj.push(lang_array);` 
`

Comment: He wants a hashed array. i.e. he wants the array to have keys and values - that can not be done with JavaScript arrays

Comment: That is not confirmed by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example you are trying to create a JS object, and not an array.

**Option 1**: Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) to collect the name and translation of each object to a new object:

```js
const data = [{"name":"title","value":"STEP-01","translation":"STEP-01"},{"name":"meta_description","value":"","translation":"meta desc"}];

const result = data.reduce((r, { name, translation }) => {
  r[name] = translation;
  
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

**Option 2**: Use a [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a collection of objects with the properties and the values, and combine them to a single object using [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```js
const data = [{"name":"title","value":"STEP-01","translation":"STEP-01"},{"name":"meta_description","value":"","translation":"meta desc"}];

const result = Object.assign(...data.map(({ name, translation }) => ({ [name]: translation })));

console.log(result);
```